# Re-applying changes that were merged and undo'd through Github

Tags: git, github, git-revert

I accidentally merged a branch to `master` through a Github PR. Immediately I reverted it (through github as well). After a few days, when that code was tested and ready to be merged, a merge and PR wouldn't actually get the code into master, because the commit already exists in github (but the code doesn't, since it was reverted.

So now I'm trying to get those changes back to master, after a weeks worth of unrelated commits. This is roughly what `git log --oneline` outputs with some comments on the relevant points:

```
54c73ee (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, staging) Merge pull request #637 from leonsas/last-night-view-metric-ceiling
...
More unrelated changes that should stay in.
...
af602f0 Merge pull request #639 from leonsas/staging
67ded36 (origin/staging) Merge <-- Here's where I tried merging the changes again, but it doesn't make it into the codebase.
...
Bunch of unrelated commits that should stay.
...
a603d0b Merge pull request #633 from leonsas/revert-628-hr-hrv-audit
c3da670 (origin/revert-628-hr-hrv-audit) Revert "Hr hrv audit"
01f2fab Merge pull request #632 from leonsas/revert-629-always-get-hrvz
5824fc8 (origin/revert-629-always-get-hrvz) Revert "Always get hrvz"  <-- I reverted changes, because code wasn't tested
b75a537 First iteration at setting the max value on the chart
6939035 Merge pull request #631 from leonsas/is-valid-fix
87b53d5 Merge pull request #629 from leonsas/always-get-hrvz   <-- These changes I want in
5b9a848 Merge pull request #628 from leonsas/hr-hrv-audit
```

What would be the best way of reapplying those changes back into master?

-- Update 1

As per Thomas suggestion, I tried the rebase solution again:

```
> git checkout -b hrv-almost-latest-changes e1d0d7b
> git rebase master-clone
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Fast-forwarded hrv-almost-latest-changes to master-clone.
> git push --set-upstream origin hrv-almost-latest-changes
```

But then the `master` is fully up to date with `hrv-almost-latest-changes`, so there's nothing to merge on a github PR.

-- Update 2

Generally, cherry picking worked fine. Specific solution was:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b hrv-merge-fix
git cherry-pick -m 1 87b53d5
(solve conflicts)
git add <files from solved conflicts>
git cherry-pick --continue
git cherry-pick -m 1 5b9a848
git push origin hrv-merge-fix
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too familiar with what github does "behind the scenes", so I would continue this in your local repository on the command line.

You should be able to use `git checkout master ; git cherry-pick -m X 87b53d5`. Refer to the `git help cherry-pick` for the value of `X`:

```
   -m parent-number, --mainline parent-number
       Usually you cannot cherry-pick a merge because you do not know which side of the merge should be considered the
       mainline. This option specifies the parent number (starting from 1) of the mainline and allows cherry-pick to
       replay the change relative to the specified parent.
```

Comment: Seems like this did the trick, with `-m 1` after some conflict solving. Reviewing code manually now to make sure everything is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the PR includes commits which are already ancestors of current master:

```
A-    ...   -F--G--H- ... -I
 \          /   |          
  B--C--D--E    revert PR  |
             |             current master
|            merge PR
old master |
           original PR
```

Since B-E are ancestors of I, an attempt to merge E into I is not going to change anything.

However, you could rebase the PR branch onto current master, to create a new string of commits which are not ancestors of I, and which still hold those changes:

```
A-    ...   -F--G--H- ... -I
 \          /               \
  B--C--D--E                 B'--C'--D'--E'
                           |              |
                           master         new PR branch
```

Now, merging E' into I is going to apply the changes.

Basically, do this:

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout E
$ git checkout -b new-pr-branch
$ git rebase master
$ git push --set-upstream origin new-pr-branch
```

and then file a new PR from `new-pr-branch`.

Comment: I actually had tried that, and just tried again, without success. See update on question for details.

Comment: @leonsas: I don't see e1d0d7b anywhere in your history. Could you paste the relevant output of `git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate`, perhaps as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/)?

Comment: Ah right, e1d0d7b is the latest commit before the merge commit. I'll try again with the merge commit (87b53d5).

Comment: Doing it from 87b53d5 had same problem (branch even with master). See this gist for output of that `git log`: https://gist.github.com/leonsas/d57a9c832d2543089d5d7d518804ac06

Comment: Tried this and it said `There isn’t anything to compare.` on GitHub when comparing `E` to `master`.